# Как убрать фокус после закрытия клавиатуры?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

На фрагменте есть 2 Edittext
При закрытии клавиатуры (кнопкой back на устройстве) клавиатура скрывается и фокус остается на edittext. Хочу убрать фокус и сохранить данные, после закрытия клавиатуры.

**UPD**: как сохранять данные понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения проблемы понадобилось создать свой EditText унаследованный от **AppCompatEditText** и переопределить метод **onKeyPreIme**

```
public class EditTextBack extends AppCompatEditText {
    ...
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            ...
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}

//in xml
<com.astend.app.util.EditTextBack
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы убрать фокус, вам нужно добавить эту строку после того как вы нажимаете на кнопку Back:

```
editText.clearFocus();
editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

но по отношению к тому полю ввода которое вам нужно. Дальше не очень понятно что значит сохранить данные в поле ввода)) Если сохранить на устройстве в память, то можно посмотреть в сторону SharedPreferences, если же у вас по каким-то причинам пропадают данные с полей для ввода, то можете сохранять данные при помощи сохранения состояния активити -  `onSaveInstanceState` например так:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
  bundle.putInt("value", value);
}
```

и дальше загружать эти данные:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  if (bundle!= null){
    value = bundle.getInt("value");
  }
}
```

Если у вас остались вопросы или что-то не понятно, то не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, постараемся помочь. Удачи :)

Comment: эх если бы все было так просто. Кнопку back в фрагменте отловить нельзя (нельзя переопределить метод), также переопределенный метод в главном activity не срабатывает когда закрываешь клавиатуру. Метод onBackPressed срабатывает только при выходе с фрагмента, а хотелось бы при закрытии клавиатуры тоже. Никак не могу найти хоть какой то способ отловить закрытие клавиатуры...

Comment: можно попробовать ловить нажатия)) ивенты нажатий, вроде в фрагментах такое есть

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press вот к примеру

Comment: да пробовал, почему то не работает

Comment: попробуйте с нуля создать фрагмент, и не внедряя никакого другого функционала сделать перехват нажатия назад.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый